# Apple TestFlight: "You will send an update to your existing testers" - internal or external?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm running a beta test with Apple TestFlight. I uploaded a new build and the activation toggle launched a dialog with this text:
`Testing for all builds of 0.0.2 will stop, and you will send an update to your existing testers.`

Does Apple mean **internal** or **external** testers? (I only want **internal** testers to get the build)
BTW: Did they change the process in the last 2 month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment activating the test toggle will make your build available for your internal testers only. To make it available for your external testers you must additionally submit it for the external beta review. This doesn't happen automatically.
After Apple approves your app for external beta testing, you will be able to invite external testers if you want to later on.